# get recordset from xml like html

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, xpath

Microsoft SQL Server. I have an xml:

```
<div class="list">
<ul>
    <li class="nr">5859. </li>
    <li class="task">task</li>
    <li class="var">Norman</li>
    <li class="var">Dave</li>
</ul>
```

What kind select method should I use to extract result  get values in one row, like:
`nr, task, var1, var2`

Comment: Could you please rephrase your question. It is not clear what you're asking

Comment: you welcome Shnugo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say: *I have an xml:*

**No! You have not! You have HTML!**

Many people think, they are the same, at least they look so similar, but HTML is **not** XML. In your example the missing closing `<div>`-tag would break any XML based approach...

Taken just the list-definition you might use XML approach:

```
DECLARE @Xml XMl=
 '<ul>
    <li class="nr">5859. </li>
    <li class="task">task</li>
    <li class="var">Norman</li>
    <li class="var">Dave</li>
</ul>' 

SELECT li.value('@class','nvarchar(max)') AS NodeClass
      ,li.value('.','nvarchar(max)') AS NodeValue
FROM @xml.nodes('/ul/li') AS A(li)
```

But I'd really strongly advise not to parse HTML with SQL-Server...

If you can be **sure**, that the given HTML **is XHTML**, it is something different. XHTML is HTML with strict compliance of XML standards. In this case, and **only in this case!**, this is a good approach...

### UPDATE: Read the XML given in comment

Two queries:

1. Fetch all `<li>` elements (if the count and naming may vary)
2. Fetch the values *side-by-side* (if the structure is fix)

Try this

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
N'<div class="list">
  <ul>
    <li class="nr">5859. </li>
    <li class="task">task</li>
    <li class="var">Norman</li>
    <li class="var">Dave</li>
  </ul>
</div>';

SELECT li.value('@class','nvarchar(max)') AS NodeClass
      ,li.value('.','nvarchar(max)') AS NodeValue
FROM @xml.nodes('/div/ul/li') AS A(li)


SELECT ul.value('(li[@class="nr"])[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS nr
      ,ul.value('(li[@class="task"])[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS task
      ,ul.value('(li[@class="var"])[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS var1
      ,ul.value('(li[@class="var"])[2]','nvarchar(max)') AS var2
FROM @xml.nodes('/div/ul') AS A(ul)
```

Comment: Shnugo you have right - its html. Your resolve is good but is possible to get i in one row like : nr, task, var1, var2?

Comment: a xml is : 
<div class="list">
 <ul>
  <li class="nr">5859. </li>
  <li class="task">task</li>
  <li class="var">Norman</li>
  <li class="var">Dave</li>
 </ul>
</div>
I need one row with columns:
nr, task, var1, var2

Regards